# Using wild card as a return type in Java

Tags: java, mockito

```
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(a)
                .isTest(Const.A,
                        Const.B);
```

In the above code cacheGet method returns a boolean value.(true/false)
I want to use a wildcard for that instead true or false.

```
Mockito.doReturn(?).when(a)
                .isTest(Const.A,
                        Const.B);
```

I want to use the wildcard in place where '?' is.

How to do it in Java?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Either you want to return true when that method gets called, or you want to return false.  What would you expect Mockito to do, as a result of you specifying the wildcard?

Comment: I'm new to Mocking, but I don't get it.  What do you expect to do with this?  You're telling Mockito to return...what? --- ha!  @DawoodibnKareem had the same idea, so I guess even newbie Mockito guy me kinda gets it.  Coolio.

Comment: ...this begs the question though...is there any way to tell Mockito to return something used or obtained elsewhere in the definition of your mock?

Comment: what do you mean by 'wildcard'? Can you show an example?

Comment: I want to write a expression valid for both true and false. Some wildcard which can use for either true or false

Comment: If you don't care what it returns but want it to be one of a set of values and not be a fixed value all the time, I guess you could return an Answer that picks a random member from a set of valid values.

Comment: In addition, having a wild card for the returned value doesn't make much sense. What value do you actually expect the mocked method to return ? Obviously mockito does not know and cannot fabricate a value for you. You need to tell it what to return.

Comment: "valid for both true and false" If your method can return **any** value and you do not care much about it, what's the point of testing then?

Comment: may be you want to pass a function to return you either true or false? In this case look at Predicate.

Comment: When you write `Mockito.doReturn ...`, you're telling Mockito what to do, in a particular case.  So, you'll have a test in which you've told Mockito to return `true`.  Or maybe you'll have a test in which you've told Mockito to return `false`.  But it's going to return one or the other.  "Return a wildcard" isn't something that Java methods do.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(cacheAdaptorCore)
                .cacheGet(OMSConst.DEFAULT_TENANCY_CODE,
                        OMSConst.APP_PARAM_DECIMAL_FORMATTER, 
CACHE_NAMES.SYS_PARAMS_CACHE_CORE);
```

tells Mockito, "Hey Mockito, if, during the following test, somehow the method `cacheAdapterCore.cacheGet()` is called with the parameters `OMSConst`..., do not really call the method, but instead make the code believe that the method returns `true`."

Now try the same sentence with "... make the code believe that the method returns ???"

See, it makes no sense.

If you want to do different tests and for some you want the method to return true, and for others you want it to return false, then you have to write separate test methods and within them, tell Mockito to return true resp. false.

Answer (score 0):

try this

String wildcard="";

if(true){

wildcard = //wildcard for true

}

else {

wildcard = //wildcard for false

}